# Parameterized complexity of Weighted Satisfiability with few variable occurrences

Tags: logic, satisfiability, parameterized-complexity

Given an integer $k$ and a Boolean CNF Formula $\phi$, Weighted Satisfiability asks whether $\phi$ is satisfiable by a model of weight $k$, i.e., a model that sets at most $k$ variables to true. This problem is W[2]-complete with respect to the parameter $k$.

Let $l$ be the maximum number of clauses that share a common variable, i.e., how often a variable occurs at most in $\phi$.
My question is the following:
**What is the complexity of Weighted Satisfiability parameterized by both $k$ and $l$?** Is anyone aware of work in this regard?

Note that this problem is NP-complete in classical complexity even if we fix $l$ to be 3, as we can introduce add copies of the variables and make them equivalent ($a\leftrightarrow a'$). This idea does not help in the parameterized setting with $k$ and $l$ as parameters, as it would require unbounded $k$ (all copies have to be set to true).

This problem seems to be connected to the model checking problem p-MC with bounded degree:
Given a first-order logic $\psi$ formula and a labelled graph $G$, decide if G is a model of $\psi$. (See Logic, Graphs and Algorithms by Martin Grohe [pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.9457&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

This problem is fixed-parameter tractable with respect to the parameters length of $\psi$ and maximum degree of $G$. In principle, Weighted Satisfiability (with bounded occurrences) can be translated to a p-MC instance, but I do not see how to achieve this with bounded degree. Vertices corresponding to variables would have bounded degree (they are only connected to a bounded number of clauses), but vertices corresponding to clauses could have unbounded degree (they may contain a large number of variables).

Comment: How would one show "that this problem is NP-complete in classical complexity even if we fix l to be 3"? $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: By a reduction from Satisfiability. First, Weighted Satisfiability with arbitrary $k$ is "plain" Satisfiability (by setting $k$ to the number of variables). Then, we replace the $i$-th occurrence of a variable $v$ with a new variable $v_i$. As a last step, we make all copies of $v$ equivalent by adding two clauses $(\neg v_i \vee v_j)\wedge (\neg v_j \vee v_i)$ for all i,j. Each $v_i$ appears at most three times (once in the original formula, twice in the two clauses establishing equivalence)

Comment: _Which_ "two clauses establishing equivalence"? $\:$ Your sentence before that would put in one pair of clauses involving $v_i$ for each other occurrence of $v$ in the original formula. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: In my previous comment I wrote that we establish equivalence for all $i,j$ - this is nonsense since it would increase $l$ too much. Sorry.

To ensure that $l=3$, we actually need an implication cycle:
If variable $v$ appears $r$ times, we have $v_1,\ldots,v_r$. We create an implication between $v_1$ and $v_2$ ($v_1\implies v_2$), $v_2$ and $v_3$ ($v_2\implies v_3$), etc, and finally between $v_r$ and $v_1$ ($v_r\implies v_1$). This implication cycle ensures that either all or none of the $v_i$'s are set to true. Now each $v_i$ occurs twice in an implication and once in the original formula.

Answer (score 1):

As I stumbled upon this today and found after some further research out that this has been solved, I want to mention this here.

[image: screenshot of abstract]

By this, the asked problem is FPT (so $t=0$ for the last sentence in the abstract).

The paper is "On the parameterized complexity of (k,s)-SAT" by Paulusma and Szeider, Inf. Proc. Letter, Volume 143, March 2019, Pages 34-36.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S002001901830228X?via%3Dihub

Here is also a version not behind the Elsevier-paywall: https://www.ac.tuwien.ac.at/files/tr/ac-tr-18-008.pdf